# LZMA Decompression with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, lzma

How do I decompress lzma files with objective c? I have the information on decompressing the files, such as header size, but I don't know how to do the process.

Comment: You can find the github link for an Objc port here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660653/763355

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an lzma decompression library such as this one: http://7-zip.org/sdk.html

That one is available in C, so you can use it directly in your Objective-C application.